# Problems pasing a matrix to my method

Tags: c++, matrix

i could not pass my matrix to my method please help me with that this is the error that

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[101]' [-fpermissive]|
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void chek(int (*)[101], int, int, int)' [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===||
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void chek(int mat1[101][101],int x,int y,int n){
    int s1=0;
    int t=0;
    while(s1==0){
            t=0;
        if((mat1[x][(y-1)])==n){mat1[x][y]=0;y=y-1;chek(mat1,x,y,n);}
        else t=t+1;
        if((mat1[x][(y+1)])==n){mat1[x][y]=0;y=y+1;chek(mat1,x,y,n);}
        else t=t+1;
        if((mat1[(x+1)][y])==n){mat1[x][y]=0;x=x+1;chek(mat1,x,y,n);}
        else t=t+1;
    if(t==3){s1=1;}
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,m,c;
    while(scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&c)&&n+m+c!=0){
        int mat1[n][m];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;i<m;j++){
                cin>>mat1[i][j];
            }
        }
        int n1=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                if(mat1[i][j]!=c&&mat1[i][j]!=0){n1=mat1[i][j];chek(mat1,i,j,n1);}
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change void chek(int mat1[101][101],int x,int y,int n)
to void chek(int **mat1,int x,int y,int n)